# I need to avoid repeating call method in android

Tags: java, android, database, threadpool

I'm working with a face-identification project , and I can't avoid to call the add_db method when camera recognized cause the camera is working all the way (I call the method when camera recognize the face). So How can I do to ensure add only  one record ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try comparing [hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) of the last addition to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could add a flag bool:

```
boolean isAdd = false;
void add_db(){
    if(!isAdd){
        // TODO: 2021/7/27 add_db  
        isAdd = true;
    }
}
```